# How to see the list of users who has liked a post in flutter?

Tags: flutter, facebook

how can I see the list of users who has liked a particular post when "X Likes" in the post is selected(like in facebook) and navigate to each user when clicked on a particular user from that list,apprciate your help

Answer (score 0):

// menuList is your userModel list with name and Like/unline(bool)

```
 var list = menuNameList.where((element) => element == true).toList();
```

// this listview in the main screen
// I assume you know how to build a Child widget(MyUserRow)

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length 
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                              MyUserRow(
                            model: list[index],
                            index: index,
                            callback: myCallBack,
                            
                          ),),
```

// in MyUser widget you have the button or on Parent view clicked which call our callback

```
 IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                 callback(id); 
                 // pass your model or just id for your new screen
                // or next screen directly 
            Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute(userId/UserModel())),
            );

        }),
```

for navigation to a new screen please refer [navigation flutter doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)